# Why CVPixelBufferGetDataSize always return 32-byte more data?

Tags: avfoundation

I am using three classes to screen capture on OSX

```
AVCaptureSession  *m_captureSession;   // AVCaptureSession
AVCaptureScreenInput  *m_screenInput;      //AVCaptureScreenInput
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput  *m_videoOutput;      // AVCaptureVideoDataOutput
```

And AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate as callback when new frame is available.

But when I call CVPixelBufferGetDataSize to get the frame size in the buffer, it always return 32 bytes more.

For example, the screen size is 2880*1800 and each pixel contains 4 bytes data (ARGB mode).
So the frame size should be 2880*1800*4 bytes as an image. But CVPixelBufferGetDataSize always return  2880*1800*4 + 32 bytes.

Does anyone know what this 32-byte is for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `CVPixelBufferGetDataSize`:

> Returns the data size for contigous planes of the PixelBuffer.

Maybe it's referring to what you get back when you call  `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress` with a "chunky" buffer:

> For chunky buffers, this will return a pointer to the pixel at 0,0 in the buffer For planar buffers this will return a pointer to a PlanarComponentInfo struct

So it's probably a `CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo` struct, with 4 8-byte  `CVPlanarComponentInfo` fields for each channel in it.